# How to close stream before return in method?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm getting `System.IO.IOException` because my file being used by another process. Is it because of unclosed stream? If yes how can I close it?

```
public static ReportClass DeserializeRep(string FileWay)
{
    Stream stream = File.Open(FileWay, FileMode.Open);
    BinaryFormatter bformatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    return (ReportClass)bformatter.Deserialize(stream);
}


var CurRep = RequestSerializer.DeserializeRep(paths[selected]);
```

Comment: Did you try `stream.Close()`?  Or better yet, a `using` statement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the using statement:

```
public static ReportClass DeserializeRep(string FileWay)
{
    using (Stream stream = File.Open(FileWay, FileMode.Open))
    {
        BinaryFormatter bformatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        return (ReportClass)bformatter.Deserialize(stream);
    }
}
```

It should also be noted that the using statement automatically calls the Dispose method of any object that inherits from IDisposible, which in this case closes the connection and then disposes the object.

IDisposible Documentation can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable(v=vs.110).aspx).